# How can I disable smart lock for passwords auto login request after Firebase Auth UI sign out?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a single activity Android app in an attempt to follow Google's recommendations. I'm using FirebaseAuth UI for authentication which apparently uses 'Smart Lock for Passwords' to save the credentials into your google account. My sign out function looks like this:

```
private fun signOutUser(){
    AuthUI.getInstance()
            .signOut(this)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                Timber.i("Sign out completed")
            }
    sharedViewModel.setUser(null)
}
```

However, once the sign out finishes, the UI immediately starts the user sign-in process, which with Smart Lock for Passwords means that a dialog pops up.  This stops users from being able to pick another account. In the github account for FirebaseAuth UI, Google mentions this issue saying:

> "Smart Lock for Passwords must be instructed to disable automatic sign-in, in order to prevent an automatic sign-in loop that prevents the user from switching accounts."

Their suggested code is:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_out) {
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .signOut(this)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                // user is now signed out
                startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But since I have only one activity I cannot do a startActivity.

So my question is how can I prevent Smart Lock for Passwords from attempting to re-login after a user signs out?

Here is the rest of my auth code if it's relevant:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    // Enable Auth listener
    startAuthListener()

    // If user is not logged in, start the login process
    if(!sharedViewModel.isUserAuthenticated()){
        startLoginProcess()
    }

}

private fun initializeAuthListener() {
    mAuthStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { firebaseAuth ->
        if (null != firebaseAuth.currentUser) {
            // User is authenticated
            // user = firebaseAuth.currentUser
            sharedViewModel.setUser(firebaseAuth.currentUser)
            //refresh all data by calling getAllCollections, getAllPois
            sharedViewModel.refreshLocalCacheData()

        } else {
            // User is not signed in so kick off FirebaseUI login
            startLoginProcess()
        }
    }
}

private fun startAuthListener(){
    authService.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener)
}

private fun startLoginProcess(){
    val providers = Arrays.asList(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build())

    // Create and launch sign-in intent
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN)
}
```

Comment: I am suffering from the same problem.

Answer (score 10):

If you wan't to disable google smart lock for your firebase UI then you can just use the

> .setIsSmartLockEnabled(boolean)

property of

> AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()

example :

```
private final Intent signIn = AuthUI.getInstance()
        .createSignInIntentBuilder().setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
        .build();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) 
    {
        //User is already loged in
        //show the main page

    } else startActivityForResult(signIn, RC_SIGN_IN); 
}
```

Here I have used a global variable to store the Intent so that I an reuse it if needed. But this is not always necessary.

This is not the correct way to approach the problem this will work but disabling smart lock is just disabling a feature that your users could have had. So a better solution would be to use smart lock.

To sign out a user while using smart lock you should add :

> Credentials.getClient(this).disableAutoSignIn();

to your sign Out function.
this will prevent smart lock from immediately re-logging in the user once signed out.

Comment: first I also did try disabling it but then quickly realised it was not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing this problem. After a bit of trial and error found that there is a setting in (API 19) Google Settings -> Smart Lock For Passwords or (API 21+) Settings -> Security -> Advanced Trusted Agents -> Smart Lock (Google). Simply disable it and then you are good to go.