# Firebase sign out is not working for google sign in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm Using the google sign an otp sign both in my project and on Logout

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

but the google signed in user is still signed. It does not signed out the google user.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Mohit, please backup your question with code. However, Firbase also uses SmartLock to sign in user automatically, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53072826/how-can-i-disable-smart-lock-for-passwords-auto-login-request-after-firebase-aut)

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
private void signOut() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```